# Terrain slope and path finding algorithm

Tags: algorithm, 3d, path-finding

I just created a 3D landscape generator and made some units to collide properly with terrain.

Now I'm encountering an issue: if I want to implement a path finding algorithm, how can I detect whether the unit cannot walk due to high slope?

Is a good idea to generate a "slope matrix map" along with the terrain generation and use it to calculate the path from a point to another one?

Thanks so much in advance

Comment: If you have normals already calculated for lightning purposes, you could use them to rapidly calculate the slope, I believe.

Comment: @SlySherZ is this the best way? I was thinking I could generate a special matrix map where models could walk, ignoring the displayed map, then perform path finding in safe without calculating slopes everytime.
Is my idea wrong? Thanks

Comment: Ideas are not right nor wrong until you test them. I do not have the experience nor the information necessary to answer your question. If memory is not a problem, that matrix could definitely be a solution to your problem. However, I wouldn't bother implementing such a thing without firstly identifying the alternative as problematic.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of setup I usually divide the map up into discrete cells (ie. pathfinding nodes) and in parallel store a set of metadata for each of those cells. Slope is a common one that you'll want to store but it's highly likely that over time you will want to store additional information. For example, you might want the terrain type to impact on the movement speed and therefore the cost of movement. I would recommend planning for having further data in the future.

I would recommend setting it up so that for each cell you have an index to a corresponding piece of metadata. Initially it could be one metadata entry for each cell but once you have it working then you can compress the metadata and only store the unique entries. Depending on the size of your world you may also want to break up the metadata spatially (ie. load and unload chunks of it as needed).

Once you have your metadata setup and the single lookup index on each of your cells all you then need to do is retrieve it when pathfinding. You can either use it to include/exclude potential neighbours or to modify the costs.